# hex values in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in haskell that i want to make some changes to it:

```
 unwords . map (printf "%02X") $ zipWith (\x y -> -(fromIntegral (ord x)) + y - 2 :: Word8) "Aa123456" [0..]
```

After running this code i get:

```
"BD 9E CF CF CF CF CF CF"
```

Basically i want the inverse of this function, so the function can get the hex values `"BD 9E CF CF CF CF CF CF"` and return `"Aa123456"`.

I am sure i would have to change the `printf` statement but how i am suppose to change the script to accept the hex values ?

Comment: You get `"BD 9E CF CF CF CF CF CF"` from `"Aa123456"`, but you want `"BD 9E CF CF CF CF CF CF"` instead of `"Aa123456"` and `"Aa123456"` instead of `"BD 9E CF CF CF CF CF CF"`? I am confused.

Comment: So you want the _inverse_ of this function?

Comment: @gspr yes i want to inverse of this function

Comment: @HananN.: That was leftaroundabout's suggestion. But anyway, I recommend that you put in some work to tidy up and clarify your question.

Comment: I also suggest that you try to reduce the problem to its fundamental component: *How can I turn a string containing a number with precisely two hexadecimal digits into the ASCII character that that number represents?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @gspr suggests, the way to solve this is to break it into smaller parts:

1. isolating each hexadecimal from the string, i.e. turning `"BD 9E CF CF CF CF CF CF"` into `["BD", "9E", ...., "CF", "CF"]`.
2. converting a hexadecimal string into an integer, e.g. "BD" -> 189
3. converting each integer into the appropriate character, e.g. 189 -> "A"

For 1, the [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3awords) function might help.

For 2, `read "0xBD" == 189`. You just need to work out how to get each hexadecimal number into the right format for `read`. (Note, that you could also write your conversion function to go directly from string to integer, it might be a nice little bit of practice.)

For 3, just invert the encoding operation, i.e.: write your equation `i = y - x - 2    (mod 256)` (where `i` is the one converted from hexadecimal, and `y` is the index in the list, and `x` is the value of the character) and solve for `x`. And `chr` is the inverse to `ord`.